# Swift | For in function to a single variable

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

i have a project with this code

```
var feeds = ["url"]

// some other code
    for feedURLString in self.feeds {
                            self.parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string: feedURLString))!
                            self.parser.delegate = self
                            self.parser.parse()
                        }
                    })
```

i would like to change the For in function to a single variable, so the

```
var feeds = "url" //without dictionary
```

thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to get rid of the unnecessary array. You could remove the loop and change your code to this:

```
var feeds = "url"

// some other code
self.parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string: feeds))!
self.parser.delegate = self
self.parser.parse()
```

In your code, the variable `feedURLString` refers to the current item in the array when looping. Since we're not looping, we've replaced this variable with `feeds`.